# Why use the PUT method in a REST API used for CRUD?

Tags: rest

I'm aware that, in the design of a REST API, the PUT method should be used to replace the entire resource and the PATCH method should be used to update it partially.

I've designed a simple REST API to perform CRUD operations in a resource:

- URL /resource , method POST (create)
- URL/resource/id, method GET (read)
- URL/resource/id, method PATCH (update)
- URL/resource/id, method DELETE (delete)

What would be the benefit of adding an endpoint with PUT, if everything it does can be accomplished with PATCH?

Comment: PATCH is a bit more _vague_ in a way, it can do a lot, not only _update_ (see [JSON Patch](http://jsonpatch.com/) for instance). Another difference is that PUT _is_ idempotent, while PATCH _can be_ (but doesn't need to). At the end though, just choose what suits best your case and eases the consumption of your API (while following the HTTP specs).

Answer (score -1):

There are various semantics around the HTTP Methods.

- POST - create
- PUT - update (sending whole resource description) (same as GET returns)
- PATCH - update (sending part of resource description.. e.g just a single field) - e.g if the the representation is really big, we may waste a lot of network resource updating the whole representation when only a single field changed). If we build a PATCH endpoint that accepts representations of single fields at the root level, we can update a large object using much smaller requests than a PUT might require.
- GET - read
- DELETE - delete

If you're working with JSON/XML/YAML/whatever, it can often make processing data faster to use PATCH but its rare (in my experience) its ever used. I think I've seen it used exactly once, maybe twice, during enterprise development.

Edit: This should clarify things https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789#section-2

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. If I use PATCH to update part of a resource (i.e. a set of resource attributes), why would I ever need PUT in CRUD operations endpoints?

Comment: because you may update multiple fields for a resource and its easier to make 1 request rather than several smaller requests which could be slower

Comment: Multiple fields can be updated in a single PATCH request.

Comment: You're right, but imagine for a minute that you attempt to update a LARGE object (a few 100kb) - perhaps edits are made frequently. You have a PUT endpoint that updates the whole resource, a PATCH request that only handles updating some small part of that resource. If many patches is slower than one PUT you use PUT (a batch update). You may also only handle patching a small part of a resource rather than all individual parts (as it requires more development time perhaps).

Comment: The same PATCH request can be used to update just one field or all fields. The API user is the one who will decide how to use it and batch API calls if desired. There isn't any performance gain in a PUT request over a PATCH request.

Comment: PATCH is for sending partial json/xml/yaml/data. If you're implementing PATCH to accept the whole data, you're doing it wrong. The whole point is PATCH can improve performance on enterprise workloads where an optimisation is necessary to maintain service levels.

Comment: Representations can get really BIG. If you just want to change one little bit of resource state, using PUT can be wasteful. This is what PATCH is for.